# What is the variable that closest resembles Sticker Price?

Tags: collegescorecard

I'm currently using the variable COSTT4_A, (Average Cost Of Attendance, Tuition and Fees) and this looks like it would best match the idea of the sticker price (the price without scholarship, fees deducted). Is this correct?

Comment: I'd personally include fees -- my college shifted a lot of costs to fees so that they could claim that they weren't raising tuition significantly.

Answer (score 3):

If your purpose is drawing comparisons to net price, it makes sense to use the cost of attendance variable you indicated because net price is generated by subtracting grant and scholarship aid from the total cost of attendance (not just tuition and fees). Total cost of attendance is the sum of published tuition and required fees (lower of in-district or in-state for public institutions), books and supplies, and the weighted average for room and board and other expenses.